# How to change video link while streaming depending on network speed AVPlayer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an `Array` of URLs with different video screen quality and I choose the link depending on the current network speed the user is on. As network changes quite often even during playback, how would I change the link during streaming?

This is my code below, the link is received after we know which network the user is:

```
 NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: stringUrl)!)
        self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.playerViewController!.player = player
        currentView.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(self.playerViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Comment: You could keep track of the current playback timestamp (where you are at in the video).  Observe network changes if they occur, stop the current video, replace the current item with the new item, then seek to time (the one you have been observing) and then continue playback.  Side note, AVPlayer does support variable playback automatically if you can get your content server to stream this type of media.